# Binding DataContext only if ObservableCollection member is not Null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ObservableCollection of Viewmodels that I want to bind to multiples of the same view but I only want to do the binding if the ObservableCollection member is not null is this possible?

```
<local:GenericView DataContext="{Binding GenericCollection[0]}"/>
<local:GenericView DataContext="{Binding GenericCollection[1]}"/>
<local:GenericView DataContext="{Binding GenericCollection[2]}"/>
```

The ObservableCollection is of variable length and not all members will be present.

Comment: Can you not just ensure there are no nulls in the observable collection?

Comment: consider using ItemsControl with ItemsSource binding to CollectionView, which has Filter for null-items

Comment: Filter it. Also, you should be doing that with an ItemsControl. The ItemContainerTemplate can just collapse itself if `{Binding}` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `GenericCollection[x]` is `null`, there is nothing to bind to. If you want to check whether `GenericCollection[x]` is `null`, or don't have an item at all at index `x`, you could use a converter that returns `Binding.DoNothing` in case there is no collection.

Something like this:

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IList genericCollection = value as IList;
        int index = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);

        if (genericCollection.Count > index)
        {
            object collection = genericCollection[index];
            if (collection != null)
                return collection;
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<local:GenericView DataContext="{Binding GenericCollection, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
```

Comment: will this binding `{Binding GenericCollection, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"` update after item in GenericCollection is changed (like `GenericCollection[1] = null` or `GenericCollection[1] = new VM()`)??

Comment: @ASh: No it won't unless you raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `GenericCollection` when it fires a `CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: @ASh: The question is about "binding if the ObservableCollection member is not null". If it's null and you don't want to bind, you can obviously not get any notifications because you never subscribe to anything. If you want to subscribe to a property, it makes no sense not to bind to it which is what the question says.

Comment: @mm8 Exactly what I was looking for, added the `PropertyChanged` event and it works perfectly. Thanks